# Eclipse android project not exporting properly

Tags: java, android, class, apk

I have been working on an android project, but after a couple of runs on the emulator, it seems to have stopped putting the classes in the .apk file. When I go 'Android Tools > Export Signed Package' I go through the steps of creating a keystore and exporting the project. When I open the .apk with 7zip, it only shows that there is: META-INF, res, AndroidManifest.xml, classes.dex and resources.arsc.

---

Error

---

07-09 17:47:01.059: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:         com.jackson.harris.android.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jackson.harris.android-2.apk]

---

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks!